# One AWS Cloud Map, Two ECS Clusters

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cloudmap

I have 2 ECS services, each is in a different AWS account (accounts A and B) and ECS Cluster.
I have created a CloudMap namespace for `services.mydomain.internal` and it is in account A. I can easily create a `ServiceDiscoveryService` to bind the ECS service in account A to the CloudMap namespace, however I'm not sure how to bind the ECS service in account B to the same CloudMap namespace, as the two are in separate accounts.

My desired end state is all services at my company are bound to the CloudMap namespace in account A such that there's a standard way to call any service
(`my-service.services.mydomain.internal`)